# Delete propel migration

Tags: symfony, propel

When I try to generate a migration class with `php app/console propel:migration:generate-diff --connection=control` but I get the error:

```
[Propel] Error                                                                                                                                 

Uncommitted migrations have been found. You should either execute or delete them before rerunning the propel:migration:generate-diff command.
```

I already generated an migration class and I want to delete the previous one. What is the command to delete it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it: It's in the `app/propel/migrations` folder.